# How to access/read files/pages on webside

Tags: php, webserver, web-development-server

in my case I get this error massage

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "RandomClass" not found in /webspace/projectfolder/pages/add_eventuser.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /webspace/projectfolder/pages/add_eventuser.php on line 10

I use

> $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

to get the exact path of the file

In my structure i organized the files like this:

projectfolder/includes/class.php where the pointed class should loaded
projectfolder/pages/initiatorpage.php where i got the Fatal Error

```html
  public class DatabaseColums
  {
    public function loadDatabase($databaseName)
    {
      $databaseName = "test";

      return $databaseName;
    }

  }
```

```html
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'includes/RandomClass.php';

  $dbinput = new DatabaseColums();

    echo $dbinput->loadDatabase();
```

I made the folder/file restrictions read/write/executeable

Cant explain to myself why I got still this massage.

What Issue is behind that.

Thank you for your attention

Comment: What is the value of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in your environment?

Comment: include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/RandomClass.php';  "/" is missing between the DOCUMENT_ROOT and /includes and make sure the path is correct.

Comment: the >$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is "/customers/homepages/htdocs/event_progress"

Comment: I checked the path and error is still displaying the `/` wasn't missing at the first time i just made a misstake by typing the question. Thank you anyway. Do you have a nother idea?

Comment: Change `include` to `require` and you should get a more file-related error (as opposed to your current class related one) if it fails to find or load the file containing the class

Comment: Are you saying that `/customers/homepages/htdocs/event_progress` is the same folder as the one you named as `projectfolder` in your example of the structure, or not? The error message suggests possibly not...remember we can't actually see your filesystem

Comment: sorry again : the issuse was the missing ` \ ` after  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`  .Cant belive this took me houers thank you so much!!

Comment: yes thats right I simplifyed the question to make it more understandable cause the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in the first case I tought it is more a file policy thing

Answer (score 1):

the problem was a missing `/` between `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and `/folder/file.php`

--right :`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].`**/** `folder/file.php`

--wrong: *`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].folder/file.php`*

Thank you @Ajmal Praveen and
@ADyson